# How to categorize Magento Grouped Product Page?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, categories, magento-1.7, product

I need to create a grouped product page on Magento 1.7

For that, I had added a product as *grouped product* and associated some *simple products* there.
Grouped product is displayed in front end as one by one in a table row. My requirement is to display this page with in corresponding **category** of associated products.

eg:- I have two Categories **Dining Tables** and **Dining Chairs**.

I had created a grouped product say **Lyn Dining set**, and associated two simple products **lyn dining table**( from *Dining Tables* Category) and **Lyn Dining Chair**( from *Dining Chair* Category). By default it will display one by one in a table row. Like this:-

```
Lyn Dining Table    Product Attributes...
Lyn Dining Chair    Product Attributes...
......................................
......................................
......................................
```

But I need that to be display with in corresponding category header. That is:-

```
Dining Table:-
Lyn Dining Table    Product Attributes...
......................................
......................................

Dining Chair:-
Lyn Dining Chair    Product Attributes...
......................................
......................................
```

For that I had edited grouped.phtml file. First of all I had fetched category name with this piece of code:-

```
        /**
         * get categories from a product
         */
        $categoryIds = $this->htmlEscape($_item->getCategoryIds());

        /**
         * looping through the array of category ids
         */
        foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
            $categoryB=$category->getName();
            }
```

By this I can able to fetch category name. But I have no idea of how to implement loop so that all products can be listed with in corresponding category. Anyone please gave a hand.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper function, like this (please keep in mind, this code is still a little rough):

public function formatProductsWithCategories($products)
    {
        $categories = array();
        $categoryProducts = array();
        $hasOrphans = false;

```
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $categories = array_merge($product->getCategoryIds(), $categories);
        foreach($product->getCategoryIds() as $categoryId) {
            $categoryProducts[$categoryId][] = $product;
            $found = true;
        }

        if (!$found){
            $categoryProducts["empty"][] = $product;
            $hasOrphans = true;
        }
    }

    $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in', $categories))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    $categoryCollection->load();

    if ($hasOrphans) {
        $categoryCollection->addItem(
            Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->addData(array(
                    'id' => 'empty',
                    'name' => 'No Categories'
            ))
        ); // assigning orphan values
    }

    foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
        if (array_key_exists($category->getId(), $categoryProducts)) {
            $category->setProducts($categoryProducts[$category->getId()]);
        }
    }

    return $categoryCollection;
}
```

Then, in your grouped.phtml template, do this:

```
<?php $categories = Mage::helper('helper_module/category')->formatProductsWithCategories($_associatedProducts); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category):?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $category->getName();?></td></tr>
    <?php foreach ($category->getProducts() as $_item): ?>
         // . . .  Existing loop here . . .
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```